# Postcss 8 plugin: How to avoid loop into Declaration function?

Tags: postcss

Hello postcss experts!

I’m updating an old plugin to postCSS 8 API but I meet some issues.

This simple postCSS plugin fall into an infinite loop:

```js
module.exports = (options = {}) => {
  return {
    postcssPlugin: 'postcss-failing-plugin',
    Declaration(decl) {
      if (decl.prop.startsWith('--')) {
        decl.prop = decl.prop.replace(/^--/, `--prefix-`);
      }
    },
  };
};

module.exports.postcss = true;
```

The documentation mention this behaviour:

> Plugins will re-visit all nodes, which you changed or added. If you will change any children, plugin will re-visit parent as well. Only `Once` and `OnceExit` will not be called again.
> [writing a plugin](https://github.com/postcss/postcss/blob/master/docs/writing-a-plugin.md)

But nothing to avoid it.

How to edit a value in `Declaration` without making an infinite loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be repeatedly adding a prefix to custom property declarations that are already prefixed, causing the declaration visitor to run infinitely.

You can use a [negative lookahead assertion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions#Basic_negative_lookahead_assertion) *`(?!)`* to match custom properties that *do not* begin with a specific custom property prefix, i.e. `^--(?!prefix-)`.

```js
const matcher = /^--(?!prefix-)/
const replacement = '--prefix-'

const ensure = value => value.replace(matcher, replacement)

// these _should not_ receive a new prefix
ensure('foo')          // "foo"
ensure('prefix-foo')   // "prefix-foo"
ensure('--prefix-foo') // "--prefix-foo"

// these _should_ receive a new prefixed
ensure('--foo')            // "--prefix-foo"
ensure('--prefixable-foo') // "--prefix-prefixable-foo"
```

As applied to your example

```js
module.exports = (options = {}) => {
  return {
    postcssPlugin: 'postcss-failing-plugin',
    Declaration(decl) {
      /** Matches a `--` property not beginning with `--prefix-`. */
      const match = /^--(?!prefix-)/

      if (match.test(decl.prop)) {
        decl.prop = decl.prop.replace(match, `--prefix-`);
      }
    },
  };
};

module.exports.postcss = true;
```